# JS - Как при нажатии на кнопку "Назад" выполнить скроллинг?

Tags: javascript, jquery, прокрутка

При стандартном возвращении на предыдущую страницу по нажатию кнопки "Назад" в браузере, функция скроллинга (также как и якорь) по умолчанию игнорируется. Как можно отключить эту установку браузера?

Требуется выполнить свой скроллинг, стандартный выполняется неправильно, так как страница меняется с помощью ajax, и при таком возвращении браузер прокручивает страницу не на нужное место.

Comment: вариант костыля: можно запоминать позицию элемента для scroll в общий источник (локальное хранилище например, или на край куки) и при попадании обратно на эту страницу делать проверку есть ли позиция и если есть делать нужный scrollTop)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, у меня так всё и реализовано, но дело в том, что при возвращении назад браузер игнорирует функцию `scroll`, она не выполняется, даже добавьте её в самый корень страницы на прямое выполнение, при возвращении она игнорируется, но а если вы перейдете на ту же самую страницу по ссылке скролл выполнится, по всем признакам эта какой-то принцип у браузера.

Comment: скорее всего браузер заново не перечитывает скрипты для интерпретатора js при возврате по истории, а берёт уже загруженные из памяти (хотя может и что-то другое)

Comment: Если вы добавите функцию `alert` она при возвращении назад выполнится без проблем, а функция `scroll` в том же самом месте проигнорируется.

Comment: Попробуйте такой плагин к jQuery: https://libraries.io/bower/jquery-backdetect

Comment: @ИгорьСаламов Попробуйте выполнить scroll через setTimeout 0

Answer (score 0):

А вы не пробовали повесить свой скрипт на событие [onpopstate](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate)?

> Событие popstate отсылается объекту window каждый раз, когда активная
>   запись истории меняется между двумя записями истории для одного и того
>   же документа.

Comment: onpopstate выполняется на старой странице, до перехода на новую страницу, а мне нужно выполнить скроллинг на новой странице.